# Selenium Query_Multiple @Test not getting executed in single class

Tags: selenium, testng

I used below code:-

```
public class Class5 {
    @Test
    public void method24() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- Test Method 1");
    }
    @Test
    public void method89() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- Test Method 2");
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void method25() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- BeforeMethod 1");
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void method26() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- BeforeMethod 2");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void method28() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- AfterMethod 1");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void method27() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- AfterMethod 2");
    }

}
```

Getting below output:-

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.13.1
Class 5- BeforeMethod 1
Class 5- BeforeMethod 2
Class 5- Test Method 2
Class 5- AfterMethod 2
Class 5- AfterMethod 1
PASSED: method89

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Here my expectation is  both @Test methods should get executed.
Can someone explain how it working here?

Also when I make `public void method89()` to anything like `public void method10()`[making it at top in alphabetical order] , in this case both @Test gets executed which is correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`@Test` should be for test methods. Now, `@BeforeMethod` would be running prior to each `@Test` method.

Same with `@AfterMethod` which would be running after each `@Test`.

You can modify, your code to :

```
public class Class5 {

@BeforeMethod
public void method25() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- BeforeMethod 1");
    }

@Test
public void method24() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- Test Method 1");
    }

@Test
public void method89() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- Test Method 2");
    }

@AfterMethod
public void method28() {
        System.out.println("Class 5- AfterMethod 1");
    }
}
```

Console output would be :

```
Class 5- BeforeMethod 1
Class 5- Test Method 1
Class 5- AfterMethod 1
Class 5- BeforeMethod 1
Class 5- Test Method 2
Class 5- AfterMethod 1
PASSED: method24
PASSED: method89
```